# Using n-grams to locate and extract numerical data from written text

Tags: python, regex, parsing, n-gram

### Problem:

I am trying to parse human generated text to extract quantitative data and output it into a table using Python.

I have about 14,000 patient records extracted from semi-structured emails.  I was able to parse out (anonymized) patient id, date, and treatment plan.  The treatment plan string is typically no more than 30 words in length and is manually written by someone.  It contains the info I am trying to extract and tabulate, along with some extraneous notes that I can ignore.  Running a bag of words model for unigrams results in a vocabulary of ~2000 words, so it is not particularly diverse.  A 6-gram bag of words results in a vocabulary file size of 2.2MB thus memory shouldn't be a concern.

With unigrams, I am able to identify which records contain drugs of interest.  If there are 20 drugs of interest, I have a Pandas dataframe that contains columns:

```
patient_id || date || raw_plan_text || drug_1 || drug_2 || ... || drug_20
```

Where the **drug_N** columns are simple boolean values indicating where the count vectorizer returns a count greater than 0.

### Goal:

What I'd like to do next is parse out the dosage and intake frequency for the medication.  A treatment plan string might contain the following substring:

```
<dosage> <drug_name> <intake_frequency>
```

But the relative ordering of those terms is variable throughout the corpus, and the **dosage** and **intake_frequency** may themselves be bigrams or trigrams.

In the end what I'd like to have is a dataframe in the following form:

```
patient_id || date || raw_plan_text || drug1 || drug1_dose || drug1_freq || ...
```

### Current Approach:

I have at my disposal some domain knowledge of typical dosages for each drug of interest and common representations of intake frequency (e.g. *"qid"* stands for *four times per day*, *"prn"* stands for *as needed*).  As I mentioned, the frequency could be a simple unigram (*"prn"*) or bigram (*"4-6hrs prn"*).  The same goes for dosage.

I plan on using the drug unigram and the dosage + frequency ngrams to colocate the relevant records and guide a regex expression to search before/after the drug name for the appropriate substrings to extract, accounting for the variable ordering of terms.  The situation gets a little hairy when a patient has more than one drug in their raw treatment plan text.  I worry about associating the wrong dosage/frequency with the wrong medication.  I think I can use punctuation as a delimiter but since I can't visually inspect all records I can't guarantee that's sufficient given the freeform of the corpus.

My question for the knowledgeable folks out there: **is there a better way to use higher order ngrams for my solution?**  I've been searching around for similar problems but a lot of what's out there has to do with text classification and sentiment analysis.  Thanks!

Comment: Honestly, such an approach seems fraught with pitfalls.

Comment: Yeah...whenever a solution centers on steadfast performance of regex, I echo your sentiment.  It feels like a fool's errand, but I'm trying to figure out if it's the problem itself or my naive approach to it.

Comment: Why use ngrams at all? Why not identify drugs of interest and then take a window around that drug?

Comment: My initial use of 1-grams was to get a feel for the corpus (e.g. the misspellings of drug names) and correct some commonly occurring typos.  Similar thoughts on the bi/trigrams for dosage and frequency: if I know what those substrings look like in the corpus, I know how to parse them.